# is there a way to use gson well to get an list with arrays that have 4 variables in java

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm making an `3D` engine using `lwjgl`.

I have tried to make a class to using a list of `HashMap` but the `HashMap` only accepts 2 variables so that does not work.

Part of my code for getting the `JSON` file

```
Gson().fromJson(string.toString(), BlockIndexFile.class);
```

the BlockIndexFile class

```
public class BlockIndexFile {

    List<HashMap<String, String>> blocks = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    public void setBlocks(List<HashMap<String, String>> blocks) {
        this.blocks = blocks;
    }

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> getBlocks(){
        return this.blocks;
    }
}
```

and the json file

```
{
    "blocks":
    [
        {
        "name": "Foo",
        "id": "foo",
        "model": "cube1",
        "texture": "foo"

        }
    ]
}
```

I expected to be able to use a `HashMap` to get the `id` and then use that to get the other variables like the `texture` and `model`.

Comment: im ok with using any other lib that does not give warnings when used ANY help would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashMap` can contain more than `2` variables. See below example how you could use it:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        BlockIndexFile blockIndexFile;
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(jsonFile)) {
            blockIndexFile = gson.fromJson(fileReader, BlockIndexFile.class);
        }
        HashMap<String, String> node0 = blockIndexFile.getBlocks().get(0);
        System.out.println("id => " + node0.get("id"));
        System.out.println("model => " + node0.get("id"));
        System.out.println("texture => " + node0.get("id"));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
id =>foo
model =>foo
texture =>foo
```

Instead `Map` you can create `POJO` and code should be much easier and concise:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        BlockIndexFile blockIndexFile;
        try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(jsonFile)) {
            blockIndexFile = gson.fromJson(fileReader, BlockIndexFile.class);
        }
        Block node0 = blockIndexFile.getBlocks().get(0);
        System.out.println(node0);
    }
}

class BlockIndexFile {

    private List<Block> blocks = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters, setters
}

class Block {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String model;
    private String texture;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Block{id='foo', name='Foo', model='cube1', texture='foo'}
```

Comment: @hydos06, I'm glad to hear that! Take a look also at [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).